# when error occurs in application redirect to root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working with a Rails application. I need it to redirect same path are root path  when an error occurs anywhere in the application, e.g. errors for undefined methods, variable not found etc.

If anyone had done something similar, please suggest me how to proceed.

Comment: Can you show the action where error occurred ?

Comment: i have no idea on this concept. i am new to rails.till now i not started code..please suggest me how to proceed.

Comment: No worries, please go through this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) also read this [link](https://www.railstutorial.org/) for getting started in rails.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the right inheritance in your controllers, you could use something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from(Exception) do |e|
    logger.error e
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Note: you need to have every controller inheriting from `ApplicationController` to make this work

Comment: thanks for your reply.. error occurs when i used that code  " undefined method `rescue_from'  "...

Comment: did you put that code in your `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`? make sure that you inherit from `ActionController::Base`!

Comment: yes it inherits from class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base..

Comment: What rails version are you using?

Comment: According to this code. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/rescuable.rb this should be available in 4.2.5.

Can you post the exception please? (with backtrace)

Comment: (A NameError occurred in properties#create:) when this type of error occurs i need to redirect that path to root_url instead of going to error page..

Comment: and your PropertiesController inherits from ApplicationController?

Comment: (class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base.) this error occur when i used your code..

Comment: Please post the whole stacktrace! To your question